# Etiqueta [itextsharp] debería ser sinónimo de [itext]

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Creo que la etiqueta [itextsharp](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itextsharp) debería ser sinónimo de [itext](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itext), ya que si bien se entiende que [itextsharp](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itextsharp) hace referencia a C# e [itext](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itext) a Java no dejan de ser la misma librería, vi en SOen que son sinónimos, y creo que tiene sentido..

¿Qué opinan?

Comment: Lo cree como pregunta porque no tengo el puntaje para realizar la sugerencia normalmente

Comment: Yo estoy de acuerdo. Son efectivamente la misma librería, y para especificar el lenguaje basta con añadir [tag:C#]  o [tag:java]

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, creo que luego de crear el sinónimo hará falta ajustar el wiki de la etiqueta para reflejar que hace referencia a ambos lenguajes y que debiera acompañarse de [c#] o [java].